# Class not overwriting with addClass

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I'm using jQuery's addClass to add a class to an tab so when clicked it'll change the class so it's obvious the tab is highlighted.

My HTML

```
<div id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li id="LinktheBand" onclick="nav('theBand')">The Band</li>
                <li id="linkTheMusic" onclick="nav('theMusic')">The Music</li>
```

My CSS

```
#mainNav li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:white;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 10px 8px 0px 8px;
    background:url('../images/transparent-65.png');
    height:40px;
    height: 25px !important;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#mainNav li:hover {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:white;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 10px 8px 0px 8px;
    background: #660000;
    height:40px;
    height: 25px !important;
    border:1px solid #660000;
}

.mainNavSelected {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:white;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 10px 8px 0px 8px;
    background: #660000;
    height:40px;
    height: 25px !important;
    border:1px solid #660000;
}
```

My Javascript

```
function nav(a) {
$('#'+a).show();
$('#Link'+a).addClass('mainNavSelected');
}
```

This works properly, I check firebug and can see the class="mainNavSelected" is added, but the list element doesn't take any properties of the new class. Firebug lists all the class items for mainNavSelected, but has them all crossed out. What am i missing to replace the class of this element?

Comment: Your question says "overwriting"; did you mean "overriding"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.mainNavSelected { 
    float:left; 
    margin-right:5px; 
    color:white; 
    font-family:Tahoma; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    padding: 10px 8px 0px 8px; 
    background: #660000 !important;
    height:40px; 
    height: 25px !important; 
    border:1px solid #660000 !important; 
}
```

This should correct the problem.  You see your CSS selector for `#mainNav li` is more specific than `.mainNavSelected`.  Because of this `#mainNav li` will always show its style before `.mainNavSelected.`

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with the CSS cascade. Styles on an id will override styles on classes, even if they are stated afterwards. Try putting `ul li a.mainNavSelected` in the CSS and it should work.

Also notice that the id's case is inconsistent between the two links.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug shows you where each CSS property comes from. If it comes from multiple places, the ones that are not in effect are crossed out.

I suspect that "#mainNav li" just has greater specificity than the class name. Try changing the selector for the class to "#mainNav li.mainNavSelected"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the properties specified by ID take precedence over the properties specified by class, so you should change those specified by ID to be a class, then remove it and add teh new class.